# Set width of container of two input type="text" boxes correctly that have display flex

Tags: html, css

MRE:

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 80%;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
}

.form-container input[type=text] {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.form-container label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter text (an AI will complete it):</p>
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <div>
      <label for="text-input-1">Recipient<br></label>
      <input type="text" id="text-input-1" name="text-input-1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="text-input-2">Donor<br></label>
      <input type="text" id="text-input-2" name="text-input-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

CSS (I added outer-container so that I'm sure I make a container that takes 80% of the width of the page but it doesn't work - it literally doesn't change anything if I use it or not):

I used display: flex to have the two boxes on the same row, i.e. next to each other instead of one below and one above. My question is why, despite using width: 80%, it seems that more than half of the width of the page isn't occupied:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex's default behaviour is to shrink to the width of the content but you've not specified the content width in any absolute units. You've said the input needs to be 50% the width of the parent div, the parent div, being a flex item will, however shrink to the content width... but that's 50% of the parent.. you get the idea.

If you want the flex item to be equal width of the parent div then the ususal way is to use `flex:1`.  See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/equal-columns-with-flexbox-its-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/) on css tricks.

Note: your `.outer-container` is 80% of the full screen width so even in this example, the input boxes won't be 100% width of the viewport. I've added some lines to show this.

```css
body {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.outer-container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.form-container input[type=text] {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.form-container label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* added this */
.form-container > div {
  flex:1;
  border: 2px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter text (an AI will complete it):</p>
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <div>
      <label for="text-input-1">Recipient<br></label>
      <input type="text" id="text-input-1" name="text-input-1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="text-input-2">Donor<br></label>
      <input type="text" id="text-input-2" name="text-input-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: `outline` should be preferred, as, unlike `border`, it does not change the width of the element.

Comment: Nope. Outlines can overlap other outlines and won't show the desired effect. Try doing it on the code above and you'll see the outline on `outline-container`, `form-container` and `form-container > div` merge together. It won't show the person asking the question the spacing of each, it'll just show one colour.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Am I the only one thinking this is counter-intuitive? If it's not, any insight of why we'd want such a behaviour?